# Maggots for turtles and bearded dragons

Tags: bearded-dragon

I have found maggots and beetles in my dried meal worm package. Are the meal worms still safe to feed to the bearded dragon and turtles with the live maggots and beetles present?

Comment: What is the company/brand of the meal worms?